# CSV to MySQL via ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, csv, import, sql-injection

I am developing an ASP.Net site where i want to allow the user to import a CSV file where the data in each row may insert or update to 1 or 2 tables in a MySQL database.  The CSV files may range from 1 to a few thousand rows and are about 6 or 7 columns wide.

I was wondering if it is possible to do this without looping though each row and calling a stored procedure while still protecting against SQL injection as this method seems like it maybe quite slow?  Also i was wondering while this is happening is this going to render my site as unresponsive to all current users?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way to do this is to import into a temp table with ASP.NET SqlBulkCopy.

Then use TSQL to copy to destination tables.

Load the csv into a DataTable.

Here is the code you need

Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(conn)

```
        connection.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(connection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock, Nothing)

                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TempTable"

            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 60000

            bulkCopy.BatchSize = 0

            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(MyDataTable)

            bulkCopy.Close()

        End Using

        connection.Close()

        End Using
```

Comment: Ok great thanks, i looked into this and it appears SQLBulkCopy doesnt work with MySQL but instead i found MySqlBulkLoader which appears to do the same thing but for MySQL.  Do you know if the MySqlBulkLoader prevents against SQL injection?

Comment: Regardless of the method you choose, you need to parse the file before you save it. Copy the file into memory and parse it line by line, and then save it to processed folder. During parsing check for SQL Injection commands.

Comment: Ok thanks is there any API calls that will parse it and remove things that could cause SQL injection?  Or will i need to classify every SQL command manually myself and remove things like semi colons and other words like "DROP", "ALTER", "GRANT"?

Answer (score -1):

```
MySqlBulkLoader loader = new MySqlBulkLoader(connection);
loader.TableName = "table name";
loader.FieldTerminator = "\t";
loader.LineTerminator = "\n";
loader.FileName = "path file";
loader.Load();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Instead, please add some explanation on how this code answers to question.